# How to Draw lines, circles with mouse?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drawing, mouse, geometry

I am working on a 2D game. I want to draw circle (its not completely like circle but player should end at the same point from where he started.

[image]

Comment: You want to draw a circle that's not completely like a circle? What?

Comment: Can you translate this post to english please?

Comment: I think this question is easily summarized to: "Potatoes?"

Comment: Too broad... you need to show what you know and explain what you have problem with. @GoldenDragon I think "circle" as in "run round in circles" - just let player wonder around along [closed polygonal chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain)

Comment: A drawing would help.

Comment: Are you looking for an 'arc' ?

Comment: I am looking to draw a circle ..

Comment: @WaqasMajeed Just post the link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to do this in 2D you can use the [Texture2D.SetPixels](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html) and [Texture2D.SetPixel](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html) methods. If you want to make it in 3D you can either create a prodedural mesh or try some clever use of the [TrailRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/TrailRenderer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link for basic idea

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22776/WPF-DrawTools

Comment: It was tagged unity3d.  Besides, this is more of a comment.

Comment: This is for windows form devs .